# JsonConvert.SerializeObject to class with non-nullable DateTime properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, data-annotations

**Background**

I have some JSON which is deserialized to a Class which has `DateTime` properties.

Sometimes the corresponding elements of the `JSON` are `null`.

When you try to deserialize the `JSON` to the class an error is thrown because a plain old `DateTime` can't accept a `null`.

**Easy but removes functionality**

So the easiest resolution is to make the accepting properties of the class a nullable `DateTime` (`DateTime?`) but if you do that there's then a lot of `DateTime` methods you can no longer use on those properties.

**Works but ... weird ?**

So in looking for alternatives I have considered the following  :

```
public class FooRelaxed
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the id.")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the Start Date.")]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the End Date.")]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public FooRelaxed() { }

    public FooRelaxed(
                  int? id,
                  DateTime? startdate,
                  DateTime? enddate)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.EndDate = enddate;
        this.StartDate = startdate;
    }
}
public class FooStrict 

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the id.")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the Start Date.")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the End Date.")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public FooStrict() { }

    public FooStrict(FooRelaxed obj)
    {
        this.Id = Convert.ToInt32(obj.Id);
        this.EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(obj.EndDate);
        this.StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(obj.StartDate);
    }
}
```

I then use these classes to  :

- Deserialize the `JSON` to the class FooRelaxed, which has nullable `DateTime` properties
- Validate the properties of the resulting object by calling `Validator.TryValidateObject` on it.
- Assuming there are no errors then instantiate the 'shadow' class, FooStrict, which has non-nullable `DateTime` properties using the FooRexlaxed instance as an arg to the constructor
- Use FooStrict for all subsequent processing

I'm sure there must be a better approach than this but I don't know what it is . Can anyone suggest a better solution ?

Comment: What do you want the serializer to do when deserializing a `null` JSON value into a `DateTime`?

Comment: @dbc - because the deserialization target is 'FooRelaxed' which has nullable DateTime properties I would like those properties to be set to null.

Comment: What I mean is, say you want to deserialize directly to `FooStrict` without needing to make the properties nullable and without needing to introduce the DTO `FooRelaxed` at all.  What value would you want to see in the `DateTime` properties when the JSON has a null value?

Comment: OP wants not null values to be there in `FooStrict`, which are anyway value types, so doesn't have scope for `Null`

Comment: What are the rules/is the contract? Are `null` values for the DateTime properties allowed or not? If not, then just let the exception flow, because you have invalid data, you cannot process. BTW you should have some classes that are only responsible for JSON de-/serialization (SRP) and map them to classes you use inside your application.

Comment: @dbc I really just wanted to be able to get through the deserialization and so then be able to establish that the incoming value was null. As it turns out the method suggested by mrinal-kamboj sets the DateTime properties to the minimum allowable value for a DateTime and this is fine for my purposes.

Comment: @SirRufo : thanks for your response. I really wanted to be able to establish all the things that were wrong in the incoming JSON and if I just allowed the exception to flow I would only know that one of the DateTime properties was null .

Comment: Then you should have a look at [JSON.NET Schema](http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/Introduction.htm) for a validation and a detailed information what is wrong with the received JSON data

Comment: @SirRufo That's very interesting. Although I'd seen that in the doco I had only really glanced at it a long time ago when I didn't really need it. It does look like it would be very useful in some circs. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decorate with appropriate `JsonProperty` attribute:

`[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]`

Or

`[JsonProperty("<NameOfProperty>", NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]`

Final code would be:

```
[JsonProperty("EndDate", NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("StartDate", NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```